# JS array убрать дубли

Tags: filter, массивы, javascript

Есть массив вида

```
['слово','слово ','новое слово',' новое слово','текст']
```

Нужно получить массив вида

```
['слово','новое слово','текст']
```

Т.е. некоторое элементы массив могут идти с пробелами как в начале так и в конце слова, нужно выполнить trim и убрать дубли из массива.

убираю дубли так

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
var arr = tags.filter(onlyUnique);
```

Но из за того что в массиве второй элемент идет с пробелом в начале

```
'новое слово',' новое слово'
```

получаю один и тот же не профильтрованный массив

Comment: Делайте tags.forEach() и в нем уже проверяйте arr.indexOf(item.trim())>=0;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из моих утилов:

```
getUnique = function (arr) {
    var i = 0,
    current,
    length = arr.length,
    unique = [];
    for (; i < length; i++) {
      current = arr[i];
      if (!~unique.indexOf(current)) {
        unique.push(current);
      }
    }
    return unique;
  };
```

Учтите, что эта функция не изменяет исходный массив, а возвращает новый.

Comment: а что тут означает вот этот символ !~ можете сказать пожалуйста ?

Comment: @Demon__ANT, это два оператора - `!` и `~`. Метод массива `indexOf(ELEMENT)` возвращает индекс элемента `ELEMENT` в массиве или `-1`, если такого элемента в массиве нет. Оператор `~`, не помню как называется и что точно делает, но для  минус единицы его применение возвращает `0`.   `0` в javascript приводится к булевскому `false`. Оператор `!` (логическое НЕ) возвращает `false` для `true` и `true` для `false`. Надеюсь теперь понятно, что условие в `if` будет выполняться только тогда, когда элемента `current` нет в массиве `unique`.

Comment: @Demon__ANT, если вам не для учебных целей, то не используйте этот код. Возьмите лучше какую-нибудь библиотеку - lodash к примеру

Comment: @alvaro спасибо большое за объяснение. Я проста гуглил для решения определенной задачи и нашёл вот это. И мне стало интересно как вы применили побитовый оператор. Мне понравилось однозначно буду использовать такой подход.

Answer (score 5):

*UPD*: Если данные кривые, а нужно отфильтровать и нормализовать, то forEach:

```
function getUniqTags(tags) {
    var results = [];

    tags.forEach(function (value) {
        value = value.trim();

        if (results.indexOf(value) === -1) {
            results.push(value);
        }
    });

    return results; 
}

console.log(getUniqTags([' слово', 'слово', '  новое слово', 'новое слово  ', 'текст  ']));
```

Comment: там у него самая главная проблема - trim, потому я и сказал делать forEach

Comment: Ну это тоже не проблема:

   ['слово', 'слово ', 'новое слово', ' новое слово', 'текст']
       .slice()
       .filter(function (value, i, array) {
           array[i] = (value = value.trim());

           var idx = array.indexOf(value);
           return idx === i || idx === -1;
       });
   ;

Comment: @lampa ['слово', 'слово', 'новое слово  ', ' новое слово ', 'текст'] -> ["слово", "текст"], Но вы правы, с idx === -1 перемудрил.

Comment: @RubaXa ах вот оно чё, ща поправим.

Comment: @lampa, на самом деле мой ответ неправильный, тут всё же нужен forEach.

Comment: @RubaXa хм, обновил.

Answer (score 5):

```
Array.from(new Set([1,2,3,4,5,5])) // [1,2,3,4,5]
[...new Set([1,2,3,4,5,5])]  // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 4):

Простой метод:

```
const arr = ['слово','слово ','новое слово',' новое слово','текст'];

const sortArr = arr.filter((it, index) => index === arr.indexOf(it = it.trim()));

console.log(sortArr) // [ 'слово', 'новое слово', 'текст' ]
```

Answer (score 3):

[[@RubaXa](/users/12604/rubaxa)](/users/12604/rubaxa) эм

```
var arr = tags.filter(function(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value.trim()) === index;
});
```

Обновил:

```
tags.filter(function(value, index, self) {
    return self.join("#,#").replace(/#\s*|\s*#/g, '').split(',').indexOf(value.trim()) === index;
}).map(function(value, index, self) {
    return value.trim();
});
```

Comment: Ну это какой-то индус-код, вы уж простите, правильным решением будет forEach, как с самого начала написал @eicto.

Comment: @RubaXa это да. Но надо было же написать еще один способ.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант еще использовать reduce

```
function uniq (array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, current) => {
    current = current.trim();
    if (!acc.includes(current)) {
        acc.push(current);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

uniq(['слово','слово ','новое слово',' новое слово','текст']);
//["слово", "новое слово", "текст"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Я использую [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

Answer (score 2):

Еще такой вариант можно использовать

```
var tagsTrim = tags.map(function (str) {
   return str.trim();
});

var filterTags = tagsTrim.filter(onlyUnique);

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Тоже вроде работает =)

Comment: @webphp мля, я то нагородил... А надо было лишь перевернуть их :D

Answer (score 2):

```
let arr = ['слово','слово ','новое слово',' новое слово','текст'];
let uniqArr = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(item=>item.trim())));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]